# Populate Input field value based on selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I am stuck trying to simplify the user inputs by automatically populating the input value based on the above selection box in a model.

Context:
I am trying to populate the account payments by using standard items.
In my DB I have the following:

```
item   | value
item 1 | Value 1
item 2 | Value 2
item 3 | value 3
```

I would have the following in my modal code

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <label class="label-control">Membership Number:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "membership" value="">
     </div>

     <label class="label-control">Rank:</label>
       <div class="input-group">
         <select type="text" class="selectpicker" data-sytle="select-with-transition" name="item" data-size="6">
            @foreach ($payments as $p)
                <option value ={{$p->item}}>{{$p->item}}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
         </div>
         
         <label class="label-control">Amount</label>
           <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "amount" value="xxxx">
           </div>
```

I would like to populate the value="xxxx" based is what selected in the item drop down.

So if Item 3 is selected from the drop down, the value 3 is populated in the value field.

I understand that I require an onchange javascript, but I am a little lost.

Saving this to the DB will not be an issue, just the javascript to update the value field is where I get stuck

Answer (score 0):

Give an `ID` "selectBox" to selectbox And "textField" to the text box. By using Jquery then you can populate its value.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#selectBox', function(){
     $('#textField').val();
});
```

Also make small change in your loop, add quotes " " to value.

```
@foreach ($payments as $p)
      <option value ="{{$p->item}}">{{$p->item}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, however this didn't work for me. Changing the selection box didn't populate the Amount field below it. I did add as suggested id="selectBox" in the select tag

Comment: Do you want to populate value when screen gets loaded..?

Comment: the Goal is when I select an item, the value of the selected item is shown in the value field. I don't need to populate this field on screen load, only when the item is selected from the drop down

Comment: @Brendan Changing my answer above.